# Ansible: Loop over a list of services and disable those from a list of unwanted services which are actually present

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using Ansible to build a base image from a base installation of RHEL7.5
One of the things I want to do is to disable unwanted services. So I do this:

```
- name: "| disable unwanted services"
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    enabled: no
    state: stopped
  loop: "{{ disabled_services }}"
  when: disabled_services is defined
```

Which works fine, testing on localhost; then I try it on a test build, and it errors because one of the services I'm trying to manage isn't even present.

Say for example that disabled_services == "ntp postfix ip6tables", but ip6tables isn't installed.  I'll get an error from the module like so:

```
ok: [udggsydasd48] => (item=postfix)
failed: [udggsydasd48] (item=ip6tables) => {"changed": false, "item":"ip6tables", "msg": "Could not find the requested service ip6tables: host"}
```

So I'm calling the service_facts module to generate a list of running services.  What ( and where) in this loop would I put the "if service in services" conditional in this loop:

```
- name: "| disable unwanted services"
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    enabled: no
    state: stopped
  loop: "{{ disabled_services }}"
  when: disabled_services is defined
```

So that it will only attempt to disable services from the array in "disabled_services" if the software is present?

I'd rather not use a fail_when: never, as this can hide other errors.

Thanks

Comment: i think you should have a separate task that you will populate a list `disabled_services_final` that exist on your `disabled_services` and the result of the `service_facts` module, then feed the `disabled_services_final` to your above task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you load the list of running `services`, use the `union` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).

```
  loop: "{{ disabled_services | union(services) }}"
```

Comment: Ah - that makes sense, thank you, but the services are labelled with .service in the services array.  I supose an earlier task is to create an array of unwanted service with ".service" appended to the name?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but more filters may help.

Comment: Yeah, I think a regex filter will do what I want, thanks.  And the union is exactly what I wanted for another area of code, so double-thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if firewalld not installed/not running you can simply ignore error message using "failed_when:"

To avoid Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg

```
- name: 'Disable firewalld Services'
   service:
     name: "{{item}}"
     state: stopped  
     enabled: no
   loop:
     - firewalld
   register: firewalld_service_disable
   failed_when: "firewalld_service_disable|failed and ('Could not find the requested service' not in firewalld_service_disable.msg)"
   ignore_errors: yes
   tags: test
```

Below is the anisble playbook execution output

```
# ansible-playbook main.yml --tags test

PLAY [all] **********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************
ok: [ANSIBLECLIENTNODE]

TASK [hardening : Disable firewalld Services] ***********************
changed: [ANSIBLECLIENTNODE] => (item=firewalld)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************

ANSIBLECLIENTNODE             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If your ansible version 2.9 and later , follow below "service_facts" method

```
- name: 'Populate service facts'
  service_facts:

- name: 'Disable firewalld Services'
  service:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
  loop:
   - firewalld
  when: ansible_facts.services[item] is defined
  ignore_errors: yes
```