# Can Ansible service-module be used for non-root daemons?

Tags: service, ansible

I need to ensure, a daemon is running, but I do not have root-access. The daemon itself does not need root anyway.

Is there a way to use Ansible's [`service`-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) somehow -- for readability -- or do I need to do it all "by hand" (with `shell` and `command` modules)?

The module's description does not seem to provide for this *except* for the `use`-clause. Can one implement a custom service-module for manipulating the service? How?

Comment: provide more information in the question about the service like the type of init system used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, when the service-provider is `systemd`, this is, indeed, possible. Use the [`systemd`-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) and set `scope`:

```yaml
- name: Enable service FOO
  systemd:
    name: FOO.service
    enabled: true
    scope: user
```

Note, that the `~/.config/systemd/user/FOO.service` has to already exist.

And then you have to have `systemd`-support for users' own services -- which on RedHat, for example, is only officially available since RedHat-8 (unofficially you can enable it in RedHat-7, but that's a separate story).

Once configured, you'll need to use the `--user` switch with `systemctl` to manipulate the service:

```sh
systemctl --user status FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

"To ensure, a daemon is running" set the *service* parameter. *sudo* is needed as a Linux default.

```
state=running
```

The *service* module does not tell the status only. Some details can be found at [disable unwanted services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137660/ansible-loop-over-a-list-of-services-and-disable-those-from-a-list-of-unwanted) and at [Using Ansible to stop service that might not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765306/using-ansible-to-stop-service-that-might-not-exist/51796343#51796343). In some use-cases module [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) might help. To develop a module you might want to start with the [dev_guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html#developing-modules).